# LINQ C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

maybe this is a stupid question, but I would like to know why this happend?

I'm creating a dictionary as follows  :

```
new Dictionary<string, object>(){{ "latestVersion", true }}
```

but when i trying to get the value to send as queryString parameters with this :

```
var x = queryParameters.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value);
```

the result is : `"latestVersion=True"`

Why is changing the value from true to True, as the services is expecting a boolean value is failing.

Comment: It implicitly convert to a `string` and calls the `ToString()` for that. My guess is that in the `ToString()` it is printed as "True". Try this in a console application: `var result = true;`

`Console.WriteLine(result);`

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Boolean.cs. It contains the code for the `boolean`. Look for `ToString()`.

Comment: But in this case, where I can not do a to upper or to  lower, cause maybe I receiving a string value as an additional param and I need the value just equals  ?

Comment: Use `((bool)x.Value).ToString().ToLower()`

Comment: Did not read your comment well enough. This only works when the type is a `bool` of course.

Comment: Is ok, I know now how to do it, but validating the type before. Thanks!!

Comment: var queryParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
{
    {
        "latestVersion", true
    },
    { 
        "SomeInteger", 20
    }
};

var t = queryParameters.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + ConvertValue(x.Value)).ToList();
    
t.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

Console.ReadKey();

string ConvertValue(object value)
{
    if(value is Boolean)
    {
        return ((bool)value).ToString().ToLower();
    }

    return $"{value}";
}

Comment: The question is closed so I cannot give an answer anymore. Sorry for the messy response.

Comment: @Moderator The problem here was not why the value "True", "False" was returned but how to solve this and get lower case. I think the question was closed too soon.

Comment: @PaulSinnema The question literally was, *"Why is changing the value from true to True"*. The duplicate answers that. And provides multiple workarounds, both in the answers and in the comments. Your comments under this question provide an abridge version of the information contained in the duplicate.

Comment: @GSerg Yeah, right. If you just interpret the title you are right. The question was answered already. But in the discussion some other issue that needed solving cropped up. In the background I was coding an example but was disappointed in the fact that I could not post it anymore. It would have helped the OP.